# Calculate row values based on previous calulated rows SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a SAS-dataset with an overall structure similar to the one below. I want to calculate all "missing" values in the MONEY-column based on the previous month's MONEY and SPEND for each ID (student).

My data looks like this (INPUT_DATA):

```
ID        MONTH       MONEY      SPEND  
01            1        1000        300
01            2           .        200
01            3           .        200
01            4           .        300
02            1        2000        100
02            2           .        100
02            3           .        150
02            4           .        100
03            1         900        600
03            2           .        100
03            3           .        200
```

I want it to look like this (OUTPUT_DATA):

```
ID        MONTH       MONEY      SPEND  
01            1        1000        300
01            2         700        200
01            3         500        200
01            4         300        300
02            1        2000        100
02            2        1900        100
02            3        1800        150
02            4        1650        100
03            1         900        600
03            2         300        100
03            3         200        200
```

How is this possible using SAS? I tried something like this using the LAG-function:

```
DATA OUTPUT_DATA;
    SET INPUT_DATA;
    IF MONTH > 1 THEN MONEY = LAG1(MONEY) - LAG1(SPEND);
RUN;
```

But unfortunately, it does not return the expected output. The data can be created using this:

```
data INPUT_DATA;
  infile datalines;
  input ID MONTH MONEY SPEND;
datalines;
01            1        1000        300
01            2           .        200
01            3           .        200
01            4           .        300
02            1        2000        100
02            2           .        100
02            3           .        150
02            4           .        100
03            1         900        600
03            2           .        100
03            3           .        200
;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier if you make a new variable that is retained.

```
data have;
  input ID $ MONTH MONEY SPEND  ;
cards;
01 1 1000 300
01 2    . 200
01 3    . 200
01 4    . 300
02 1 2000 100
02 2    . 100
02 3    . 150
02 4    . 100
03 1  900 600
03 2    . 100
03 3    . 200
;

data want;
  set have ;
  by id;
  new_money = coalesce(money,new_money);
  output;
  new_money + -spend;
run;
```

Results:

```
                                         new_
Obs    ID    MONTH    MONEY    SPEND    money

  1    01      1       1000     300      1000
  2    01      2          .     200       700
  3    01      3          .     200       500
  4    01      4          .     300       300
  5    02      1       2000     100      2000
  6    02      2          .     100      1900
  7    02      3          .     150      1800
  8    02      4          .     100      1650
  9    03      1        900     600       900
 10    03      2          .     100       300
 11    03      3          .     200       200
```

Add a DROP and RENAME statement if you want get rid of the original variable and re-use its name.

```
drop money;
rename new_money=money;
```